# Can I use msgsnd() to send messages to specific child processes?

Tags: c, child-process

I have a program with 10 children and their parent.  Is there any way for the parent to send a message via [`msgsnd()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgsnd.html) to a specific child? I mean, child 1 should receive `msg1`, child should 2 receive `msg2`, etc....

Comment: Are you talking about parent/child IPC? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170647/fork-parent-child-communication

Comment: yes, but with msgsn, no pipes

Comment: You haven't specified enough information in the question for anyone to be able to answer.  What IPC mechanisms are you planning to use?  Are there any artificial constraints on what you can use?

Comment: Can I use different type of msgsnd to each child receive his message independently

Comment: Note that you need to decide, in part, how the children are going to receive the message.  The [`msgrcv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgrcv.html) function allows you to control which messages are received, so by allocating each of the 10 children a number, you can send a message that only the child will receive.  So the answer to "Can I use a different type of `msgsnd()` message to each child" is yes.